# Set default value in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume there is a table

```
Emp_id  Name  Comments
1       Ana   Test
2       Dana  Test1
3       Fiona Test2
```

The below query will retrieve all the records from my table, and now i have to retrieve date SysDate + 5 Working days (Excluding Saturdays and Sundays) as well which is not in table

```
select emp_id,Name,Comments from Employees
```

And the expected output is

```
    Emp_id  Name    Comments   Date
    1       Ana     Test       28.10.2016
    2       Dana    Test1      28.10.2016
    3       Fiona   Test2      28.10.2016
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_add_a_day_hour_minute_second_to_a_date_value

Comment: @juergend - Did you even read the question? It wasn't about adding five days, it was about adding five BUSINESS days. It's OK to want to help, but if you don't even take the time to read and understand the question, you aren't helping much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula should add 7 total days if SYSDATE is a business day, but it should add only 5 days if SYSDATE is a Sunday and only 6 days when SYSDATE is a Saturday. This can be done with a CASE expression:

```
... SYSDATE + case to_char(SYSDATE, 'Dy') when 'Sun' then 5
                                          when 'Sat' then 6
                                          else            7 end as my_date...
```

("Date" is a reserved word in Oracle, don't use it as a column name.)

Another thing - if you really need a date (and don't need the same time-of-day as the "current" time) you may also want to wrap the entire expression within `trunc(....)` so you get just the date, with the time set to `00:00:00`.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy I randomly checked and only after u commented, i noted that the query results are incorrect when date falls on Monday and Friday.

Comment: Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

```
 select emp_id,Name,Comments, 
           (SYSDATE + case to_char(SYSDATE, 'DY') 
            when 'Sun' then 5
            when 'Sat' then 6
            else 7 
            end) Date
            from Employees
```

Comment: But the query should exclude Saturdays and Sundays :(

Comment: @ Annie. You edited your question. I saw now.  I understand your question